# Comparing two groups with non-negative integers?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Can I use Mann Whitney U Test (Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test) to test for differences between two populations for count data (i.e. non-negative integers)?

Comment: Of course, you can perform the 2-sample Wilcoxon test. // Whether it is the best choice and whether it will tell you what you want to know depends on situation and your goals. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @BruceET Thanks, I have a data of number of visits to the hospital emergency department 60 days before and 60 days after COVID19. So, the unit of analysis (i.e. the observation would be the day(s)). Basically, the it would be a before-and-after comparison. I was thinking of using 2-sample independent t-test for this, but this is not continuous, it is discrete, i.e. count data or non-negative integers, so perhaps, it may not be suitable. Would Mann Whitney U Test be more suitable since it is non-parametric?

Answer (score 0):

A t test assumes data are normal and I wonder whether
admissions counts Before or After Covid would be normal.

A 2-sample Wilcoxon (rank sum) test assumes the data Before
and After are roughly of the same shape (including equally variable), but perhaps shifted
upwards after.

If there is a weekly pattern for admissions (maybe tending to be lower on weekends) and your Before and
After counts match days of the week, then you should consider
a paired test. The paired Wilcoxon test is a signed rank tests
on differences. (You might check whether there is a positive
correlation between the 60 Before and 60 After counts.)

If you want to show your data (2 rows of data, counts separated by commas), or Before and After histograms, or even Before and After
means and variances, someone might be able to give more specific advice.